# Modify <Select /> component of ant-design to allow progressive data loading

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, antd

I'm building a React application with Ant-design.
I would like to build forms with lazy-loading functionality on  component to avoid to load a to heavy payload of data to fill the component.
For now, I'm using the scrollbar position and loading pages when the bar comes at a specific treshold.
Which means that if there isn't scrollbar then the lazy loading doesn't work anymore.
Is there a more efficient way to do it ?

I'm using ant-design 3.X and react 16.12 with a .Net Core API.

Here is my current implementation :

```js
export const onScroll = async (event, dispatch, pageSize, totalCount) => {
    event.persist();
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.scrollTop + target.offsetHeight >= target.scrollHeight - 32) {
        if (pageSize >= totalCount) return;
        getDatas(dispatch, 1, pageSize + 10);
    }
}
```